# How to pull down formulas in a new Google Sheets tab?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a newly created Google Sheets tab with 1.000 rows and two formulas:

- in F2: `=IFERROR((VLOOKUP(B2,sv!$A:$D,2,0)/C2+IF(C2=ctr!A$2),""))`
- in G2: `=IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT("."&A2&"/","\.([^.]+\.[^./?]+)(?:/|\?)"),"")`

How can i pull this formulas down to 300.000 rows? Without to manually pull them and wait until Google Sheets scrolls the tab 300.000 rows to bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- select cell that holds the formula
- press **<kbd>`CTRL`</kbd>** + **<kbd>`SHIFT`</kbd>** + **<kbd>`DOWN ARROW`</kbd>**

  (and keep tapping **<kbd>`DOWN ARROW`</kbd>** till you reach the desired last row
- press **<kbd>`CTRL`</kbd>** + **<kbd>`ENTER`</kbd>**
- done

---

or use ArrayFormula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B, sv!A:D, 2, 0)/C2:C+IF(C2:C=ctr!A2, 1, 0), ))
```

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT("."&A2:A&"/", "\.([^.]+\.[^./?]+)(?:/|\?)"), ))
```